# Using Font Awesome in android app

Tags: android

Im using Font Awesome in my website and I'm I built a website API that my android application suppose to read.

In some labels there are font awesome along with a text.

I successfully implemented Font Awesome in my application but it works for me only when it's hardcoded or as string inside the XML file.
My problem is that I'm reading the font awesome from an API and I'm setting the text with TextBox.setText() method.

I'm facing really strange problem:

```
holder.gamesTitleTextView.setText("\uf135 " + gamesTitle); // Hardcoded, works
holder.gamesTitleTextView.setText(R.string.fa_icon_rocket + gamesTitle); //From saved string, does not work (returns some numbers)
```

Saved string is: `<string name="fa_icon_rocket">\uf135</string>`

Since I have abbility to change my API, if my API contains the font awesome string, **\uf135**, it shows it as a text and not as font-awesome icon.

Anyone has any way to solve it and use font awesome with the **setText()** method from a web API?

Comment: Have you tried escaping your slash? `\\uf135`

Comment: Do you mean escaping the slash In the API or in the string.xml file?

Comment: Yes I still get a bunch of numbers

Comment: Are you adding a space too? because `"\uf135 "` this has a space

Comment: I've had this space, but even after removing it, with and without the escaping slash it shows bunch of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below in java code, its working fine for me:

```
public static final char FA_ICON_ROCKET= "\uf135";
```

Comment: Please read the question. OP needs to include the Unicode characters dynamically, from an API he has. Hard-coding them as character constants isn't an option here.

Comment: @TomG is right. I need to read the font meta from web API and I'm trying to avoid using it in the app directly..